# How to automate QR code scanning using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can anyone tell how can we automate the process of scanning QR code from a website using selenium webdriver with python.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial of how you can do it with java however `zxing` library also available in python : 
https://medium.com/@eliasnogueira/read-qr-code-content-with-selenium-and-zxing-59f255430fe0

And here is a github project about it : 
https://github.com/eliasnogueira/selenium-read-qrcode

Python Example : https://github.com/dlenski/python-zxing

Comment: I could not find the python documentation for it. Can you provide me the link for the python documentation.

Comment: Here is a example : https://github.com/dlenski/python-zxing @HimanshuBansal